# What is the best method for converting List<String> to String

Tags: java, string, arraylist

So I've been looking back on code I've written almost a year and a half ago trying to fix it and I found this function that has got me confused. I searched for a method to do the same thing and found a pretty decent function and I'm curious at what would be better.

Function A:

```
public static String listToString(List<String> list){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (list != null && list.size() > 1){
        sb.append(list.get(0));
        for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++){
            sb.append(", " + list.get(i));
        }
    }else if(list != null && (list.size() == 1)){
        sb.append(list.get(0));
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Function B:

```
public static String listToString(List<String> list) {
    String str = "";
    for (String s : list) {
        str += s + ", ";
    }
    return str;
}
```

Now I wrote Function A within my first couple months of learning Java so I probably didn't know best though is there any reason I should stick to this method?

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html

Comment: Function B is bad, as `String` concatenation in loops can't be optimised by the JVM at runtime and is woefully inefficient (creating lots of short lived objects that need to be GC).  Function A is in the right direction, except `sb.append(", " + list.get(i));` defeats the purpose and should be `sb.append(", ").append(list.get(i));`

Comment: Apache Commons has `StringUtils.join`.  Don't re-invent wheels.

Comment: @MadProgrammer The main problem isn't the object allocation, but the fact that `str3 = str1 + str2` requires copying all of the chars in `str1` and `str2` into the `char[]` that `str3` uses (twice, actually: once for the temporary `StringBuilder` and once for the new `String` it produces). If you do `str += foo`, that means that each time around, the previous `str` chars will be copied to create the new `str`. The original str's chars are copied N times, the first loop's str chars are copied N-1 times, etc. It's an N^2 operation, which is worse than the object allocation.

Comment: @yshavit I was under the impression that String consternation in a loop didn't involve a StringBuilder ... Haven't really looked on to it do I could be over simplifying

Answer (score 1):

Function A is preferable since it is using only one instance of StringBuilder while code from Function B executed in loop

```
str += s + ", ";
```

is equivalent of

```
str = new StringBuilder(str).append(s).append(", ").toString();
```

so in each iteration you have to:

- create new StringBuilder
- copy content of current string to this StringBuilder
- now you can add `", "` and `s`
- create and return new String based on current content of StringBuilder

(so in each iteration your need to read entire string again, and again, and again...) while in scenario B you just focus on adding new characters to single StringBuilder

---

Anyway since Java 8 you don't need to focus this much on writing methods which can concatenate collection of strings. You can simply use `StringJoiner` class or simpler just invoke
`join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements)` method from String class which will use `StringJoiner` for you. Code of this method looks like:

```
public static String join(CharSequence delimiter,
        Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(delimiter);
    Objects.requireNonNull(elements);
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(delimiter);
    for (CharSequence cs: elements) {
        joiner.add(cs);
    }
    return joiner.toString();
}
```

---

Note that `Objects.requireNonNull(delimiter);` will throw NPE in case of `null`, so if you want to avoid it you can write your own version of this method and replace this tests with something more like

```
if (delimiter==null || elements==null) return "";
```

or if you would like to allow delimiter to be null

```
if (elements==null) return "";
if (delimiter == null) delimiter = "";//use empty string as delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

**Apache's commons lang**, just appends

```
 StringUtils.join(list);
```

or
 separate by characters.

```
StringUtils.join(java.lang.Iterable,char)
```

**Java 8.0** onwards, first argument is to separate elements

```
String joined = String.join("", list);
```

Answer (score 1):

check [Joiner](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Joiner.html) on guava

```
    String s= Joiner.on(",").join(lists);
```

Check below output test

```
    List<String> lists=new ArrayList<String>();
    lists.add("a1");
    lists.add("a2");
    lists.add("a3");
    lists.add("a4");
    String s = Joiner.on(",").join(lists);
    System.out.println(s);
```

ouput:

```
a1,a2,a3,a4
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides using libraries you could use

(the pattern I've seen most often)

```
public static String listToString(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for (String string : list) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            sb.append(", ");
        sb.append(string);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

(also quite common)

```
public static String listToString(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String separator = "";
    for (String string : list) {
        sb.append(separator).append(string);
        separator = ", ";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

(shortest, bit hard to read)

```
public static String listToString(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();)
        sb.append(iterator.next()).append(iterator.hasNext() ? ", " : "");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

(could be the fastest since no extra conditional jumps in the loops)

```
public static String listToString(List<String> list) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        sb.append(iterator.next());
        while (iterator.hasNext())
            sb.append(", ").append(iterator.next());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Or something else that is readable & short like B but uses a `StringBuilder`. What you don't want to have is `+` string concatenation in a loop. That creates temporary objects.